# How do make variables acessible to all functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, getelementbyid

I'm curious about what I'm not understanding in this code snippet...

Why does this work?

```
 function insert_number(number){
   var output = document.getElementById('output');
   output.value += number.value;
 }
```

but this doesnt work?

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function insert_number(number){
  output.value += number.value;
}
```

Does it have something to do with the way the variable `output` is defined?

Also how would I write the `output` variable within the function `insert_number()` while still making `output` available to all other functions in my script (even if it means having to escape the variable out of the function, or specifically send it to another function as a parameter)?

Note: All my code is in an external ".js" file

the complete context of the code as of right now is this (I will be adding more later):

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function insert_number(number){
  output.value += number.value;
}

function clear_output(){
  output.value = "";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work? looks fine to me

Comment: Is that the complete context of your code or is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, they both work, as long as the DOM element at

```
document.getElementById('output')
```

exists when the code is run. The important difference is that your `insert_number` function probably runs after the DOM is loaded, unlike the bare output assignment in the second example.

> Also how would I write the `output` variable within the function
>   `insert_number()` while still making output globally available to all
>   other functions in my script?

Good JavaScript developers try to avoid global variables where unnecessary, but the simple answer is this:

```
var output; // declared, but as yet undefined

window.onload = function () {
    window.output = document.getElementById("output");
}

function insert_number(number) {
    output.value += number.value;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by this `your insert_number function probably runs after the DOM is loaded, unlike the bare output assignment in the second example.` ?

Comment: @Proud_to_be_Noob `<script>` elements in HTML run as soon as the browser encounters them, but the DOM is not complete until potentially much later. In your second example you run `document.getElementById('output')` before the element with the given id has actually been added to the DOM. `document.getElementById('doesntexist')` returns `null`.

Comment: so is the only way to fix that issue to use the `window.onload = function()` or is there another way.  you said `Good JavaScript developers try to avoid global variables where unnecessary` how can i do this while avoiding global variables?

Comment: [Paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9101306/418413) shows one way to avoid *unnamespaced* global variables, but it may also be more complex than you need. It's better not to be pedantic about this kind of thing, especially if you're only adding one variable to the page. Another approach is simply to move your (example 2) code to the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` closing tag. You could also just call `document.getElementById` when you need it, instead of assigning it to a value. There's a mild performance cost to this approach, but no additional globals.

Comment: Well, it seems from what you said that the code you posted is my best option, or one of them. I will mark that your answer is my accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will keep only a single object/namespace in the global scope:

```
(function(global, d) {
    var output = d.getElementById('output'),
        myApi = {};

    myApi.insert_number = function(number){
      output.value += number.value;
    };

    //export your api to the global scope
    global.myApi = myApi;
})(window, document);
```

Now you can call `myApi.insert_number(5);` You now have a closure that has access to the `output` variable so you can add additional functionality to your API without having to access the DOM each time.

Just a reminder, JavaScript like this should be placed at the bottom of your page just above the closing `</body>`

I would reccomend watching this video on global scope: http://www.watchmecode.net/javascript-scope

Comment: This seems a little complicated for the simple functions I'm trying to use.  I will study more about this later.  Thanks though.

Comment: Not a problem. One thing I will point out is that most JavaScript code `starts out simple` but then grows quickly out of control. I personally always try to plan for growth and it tends to make adding additional functionality and refactoring much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with global variables.

You are probably having the script inside your `head`. At that stage, the DOM is not fully built yet and the element with ID `output` does not exist yet. Hence `document.getElementById('output')` will return `null` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/jv2CW/)).

But if you are probably calling `insert_number` some time after the DOM was built, as response to some user interaction. In that case the element will exist.

The simplest solution would be to put your code before the closing `body` tag ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/jv2CW/1/), notice the different jsfiddle settings and/or inspect the source).

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason your code is not working is because the DOM is not loaded when you call  `var output = document.getElementById('output');`

Move the code below where the output div is and it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable, without using "var", the variable always becomes *global*. More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: yuck w3schools.com UGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG... I implore you to avoid referencing that bad reference site. Should have a filter that blocks that as a cursed word.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: okay but that only partially answers my question, and I already knew that much (I will rephrase my question). I really need to know why the first code snippet works but the second does not.

Comment: It does answer the literal question (How do globals work)... But it's not what the OP intended to ask

Comment: Variables declared in the global space *with* the `var` keyword are also global, as well as variables defined as properties of the global object.